# How to find most frequent element in a list with python

Tags: python, list, frequency

I want to find most frequent element in a list, but my code is not working. What should I do? 
I'm getting

> **IndentationError: unexpected indent Error

My code

```
A = [7, 9, 2, 7, 8, 3, 5, 7, 11, 3, 7]  
def mstfrqent(A): 
counter = 0
num = A[0] 
for i in A: 
    curr_frequency = A.count(i) 
return i
print(mstfrqent(A))
```

Comment: Read up on how to indent your python code, you don't have proper indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another for loop.

Btw you should give more understandable list names, it will be more efficent for work.

```
A = [7, 9, 2, 7, 8, 3, 5, 7, 11, 3, 7] 

def mstfrqent(A): 
    counter = 0
    num = A[0] 

    for i in A: 
        curr_frequency = A.count(i) 
        if(curr_frequency> counter): 
            counter = curr_frequency 
            num = i 

    return num 

print(mstfrqent(A))
```

Comment: There is not "another for loop" in your solution and I disagree with "should use". Your code change might fix the problem but for counting you should use `collections.Counter` (e.g. `collections.Counter(A).most_common(1)`).

Comment: Oh i see, it will be "if". Why did i write "another for loop" sorry. And my code written according to @protector99's code.
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Right. If you want to build up on the OPs code then your solution could be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Execute below code. Seems like u were facing only **Indentation Issue** n thats all.

```
A = [7, 9, 2, 7, 8, 3, 5, 7, 11, 3, 7]  

def mstfrqent(A): 
  counter = 0
  num = A[0] 

  for i in A: 
    curr_frequency = A.count(i) 

  return i


print(mstfrqent(A))
```